# Programmatically build WXS into MSI

Tags: c#, command-line, wix

I will try to make this as clear as I can, but if you have questions or don't completely understand let me know.

I have a program that creates a WXS (WiX source code file) from scratch, and tests it to make sure it is valid.  I would like the next automatic step to be the actual building of the WXS using Visual Studio (I am working with VS 2008 Developers Edition/Team Suite Edition).  I know that a WiX project (with WXS included in it) can be build from within VS, and the WiX comes with command line utilities for building as well. What I am looking for is the best option to go with. The program is a command line utility with no GUI.  I know it is possible to use the command line from within my program, but I don't know how to use it with variable destinations and file names for the created file.  A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

build your WIX project in the visual studio and look at the Output window to see what is WiX actually running. then just copy paste those lines into your build proces.

Comment: @Mladen: I really feel like a fool for not thinking of that!  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since the project was integrated with the WIX project inside Visual Studio, once I ran

> msbuild.exe /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release .\SPIder.sln

The whole project was compiled AND the msi file was also created as if I did it from the IDE...

[image]

NewSPI2GUI = the WIX files

SPIder = my WPF app