# Wix Bootstrapper multi-language

Tags: c#, xml, windows, installation, wix3

I have a Wix installation set up. I am using Wix Bootstrapper to make windows. All installation windows are made by their own. I need to localize them, I can not solve this question in any way.

Answer (score 4):

Not a lot of time, this will just be a bunch of links, hopefully enough for you to help yourself.

---

***WiX Burn localization***: Maybe have a look at this project on github for localization of your WiX Bundle (which I haven't really tried yet - this is someone else's sample): https://github.com/frederiksen/Classic-WiX-Burn-Theme.

I don't think this sample has localized MSI files, just the WiX Bundle. I am not sure.

---

***MSI Localization***: WiX has some support for standard dialog sets in a number of languages, but you need to localize your own, custom dialogs. I have seen some problems with these dialogs, but I usually get things working using the "Mondo" set.

I lack a full overview, but let me try to give you some pointers:

***WiX Tutorial***:

- [Localizing your custom setup dialogs](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/think-localized/)
- [User Interface In General](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/)
- [Localization](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/localization/)
- [User Interface revisited](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/)
- [More on custom dialogs](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/dontcha-speak-english/)

***WiX Documentation***:

- [How To: User Interface and Localization](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/)
- [WixUI Dialog Library](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/index.html)

---

***Using WixUIExtension*** (standard UI):

- [What else do I need to show the license aside from WixUILicenseRtf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479455/what-else-do-i-need-to-show-the-license-aside-from-wixuilicensertf?noredirect=1&lq=1) (no Visual Studio)
- [WiX installer msi not installing the Winform app created with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970743/wix-installer-msi-not-installing-the-winform-app-created-with-visual-studio-2017/47972615#47972615) (Visual Studio)

---

***IsWiX***: Just trowing this is - I don't think there is much localization here, but there are some sample test projects that are useful. Also, you can find more advanced WiX samples and tutorials from [the IsWix project](https://github.com/iswix-llc). Essentially a GUI front end for generating WiX MSI files. [Here are the actual tutorials](https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials). And the tool itself: https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix. And [the blog](http://iswix.com/).