# Wix Automation from reg files

Tags: windows, wix, registry, installation

I have 2 **`*.reg`** files and I want to create an **MSI** with **WiX**.
I have used **`heat.exe`** to create WXS files from reg and then I see I can use **`candle.exe`** and **`light.exe`**, but I am doing something wrong, I assume it’s something easy but I am new to this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on here. But I assume you have created a WiX markup file *.wxs and you want to compile it to an MSI file. You can use Visual Studio to do so if you install the Visual Studio extension in addition to WiX itself. Both can be found here: http://wixtoolset.org/releases/

Maybe try to read this answer: [**How to compile WiX using Visual Studio or Command Line**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481391/129130). And [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26358381/129130).

---

The exact command line parameters for **`candle.exe`** and **`light.exe`** as well as **`heat.exe`** or any other WiX tool can be obtained by invoking the tool with **`/?`** from a command prompt:

```
light.exe /?
candle.exe /?
heat.exe /?
```

For the above to work the WiX bin directory must be added to your system's Path variable, or you must cd to the WiX bin folder (**`"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin"`**) and invoke the command from there.

Some further info here: [Linker (light.exe)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html)

Comment: Thank you , I have used heat which successfully created 2 wxs files from the reg files. Then I believe I can use candle to create wixobj files and then finally use light to create an msi from the wixobj files. I tried the above but the final msi doesn’t actually add the registries so I assume I am missing something or my main wxs is wrong

Comment: You need to update your question with the actual WiX markup.